# Does Maxima have an equivalent function of Mathematica's Full Form, that maps the expression tree?

Tags: tree, expression, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math, maxima

Mathematica has a function FullForm that

> prints as the full form of expr, with no special syntax.
>   http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html

Does Maxima have an equivalent function?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but there are various functions which are working in something like the same spirit.

(1) `grind` prints a readable representation of an expression, i.e. the output of `grind` can be read by the Maxima parser as an input. E.g. `grind(a^2 + b/c)`.

(2) `op` and `args` obtain the operator and arguments of an expression. E.g. `op(a=b)`, `args(a=b)`.

(3) The Lisp function `?print` outputs the Lisp representation of an expression. E.g. `?print(a+sqrt(b/c))`.

If you say more about what you are trying to accomplish, maybe I can give some specific advice.